# Как лучше конвертировать .doc .docx в html одним файлом в .NET

Tags: html, asp.net, ms-word

Доброго времени суток, хотелось бы сделать конвертацию из .doc файла в один файл html, в интернете нашел несколько библиотек [Библиотека 1 ITextSharp](https://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) и [Библиотека 2 PDFSharp](http://www.pdfsharp.net/), но из-за малоопытности не удается найти хороший рабочий пример, как быть с картинками(их можно конвертировать в base64, но как их вытаскивать из файла а потом вставлять код не понятно).Может кто-нибудь похожее делал и может поделиться примером ? Буду очень благодарен за Ваши ответы!